# Equatable in Swift

Tags: swift, iequatable

I am trying to define Equatable using Swift structs. I am getting an error on the line `func ==` saying `Operators are only allowed at global scope`.

```
struct ShoppingList {

    var shoppingListId :NSNumber
    var title :String

    init(title :String) {

        self.title = title
        self.shoppingListId = NSNumber(integer: 0)
    }
}

extension ShoppingList {

    public func ==(lhs :ShoppingList, rhs :ShoppingList) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what it says. Move the operator function definition outside of the extension. It's done at a global scope.